# Today Extension App Group not work swift ios 11

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

i've a problem with sharing data from my app to Today extension.
I've enable the app group in capabilities.
In my app controller I've this

```
var defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.mygroup")!
defaults.setValue("today extension text", forKey: "customKey")
defaults.synchronize()
```

And this is my Today Extension code:

```
class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {

@IBOutlet var TimerText: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: (@escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
    completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
    let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.mygroup")!
    let myString = defaults.value(forKey: "customKey")

    if(String(describing: myString) == "" || myString == nil) {
        TimerText.text = "no data"
    } else {
        TimerText.text = String(describing: myString!)
    }
}
```

}

The widget after lunch application show always no data although in the m ain app the variable is correctly set.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added `group.com.mygroup` to you app groups under the Capabilities section in your app's target and your today widget target?

Comment: hi jake, yes add

Comment: In today extension I've a entitlements file with set App Groups. Xcode set automatically when enable or add group in main application

Comment: Did it work before iOS 11 or has it never worked in the first place?

Comment: Now work! I’ve delete and recreate a project.